# from textbox to listview

Tags: c#, listview, textbox

I'm working on a C# app with a multiline textbox and a `listview`.

The textbox stuff looks like this:

```
John Smith
Joe Bronstein
Susan Jones
Adam Feldman
```

The listview has two columns: `Date` and `Name`.

So far, I can put the current date into the listview's Date column. Next, I need to copy the names into the Name column. The `listview` should look like this:

```
Date      Name     
6/27/2013 John Smith
6/27/2013 Joe Bronstein
6/27/2013 Susan Jones
6/27/2013 Adam Feldman
```

So how do I copy the name from each line in the `textbox` into the `Name` column on each line in the `listview`?

Answer (score 2):

This will add all names from textBox to listView with current date:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
foreach (var line in textBox.Lines)
    listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { date, line}));
```

*How it works:* We are enumerating `TextBox` property `Lines` which returns names line by line. For each line created new `ListViewItem` with array of strings for each column in your `ListView`. Then item is added to listView.

Answer (score 0):

**Lazyberezovsky** answer works perfectly.

But if you have added already an item in your `Listview` and you want to add the lines after the fact that you have added already the `Dates` (honestly I doubt this but just a guess). Then you need to you use `SubItem` to add on each rows to a new column. Now, given of course that your `ListView` has the **same number** of `Items` as the **number of** `Lines` in your `Multiline` `Textbox`.

So, that your code would probably look like this:

```
string[] line = textBox1.Lines; // get all the lines of text from Multiline Textbox
int i = 0; // index for the array above
foreach (ListViewItem itm in listView1.Items) // Iterate on each Item of the ListView
{
   itm.SubItems.Add(line[i++]); // Add the line from your textbox to each ListViewItem using the SubItem
}
```

Otherwise again **Lazyberezovsky's** answer works perfectly and the right solution to your problem.